# How to get address of contract interface

Tags: solidity, contract-design, addresses, interfaces

In the contract below, how to look up address of `tokenContract` ?

> Operator != not compatible with types address and contract Token
>               if(msg.sender != tokenContract) throw;

```
contract Token { }

contract A{

    Token public tokenContract

    function A(address addressOfTokenContract) {
    tokenContract = Token(addressOfTokenContract);
    }


    function B() {
    if(msg.sender != tokenContract) throw;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can cast the contract to an address type with

```
msg.sender != address(tokenContract)
```